# Electron issue with HTTPS to fix Stripe warning

Tags: node.js, express, electron, stripe-payments

I have an Electron app with Express JS Server so I can use Google Recaptcha.

I also added Stripe Elements in Electron with https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js.
The backend has HTTPS and handles the webhooks from stripe correctly.

My problem is that inside Electron either if it's build with default config with **://file or express.js**, **it's not HTTPS**, with express.js it's **http://localhost:${port}** and I receive a warning about Stripe that is **not on HTTPS**.
On production Stripe works with no issues even with that warning.

Now if Electron is a desktop app, it communicates with my API that has HTTPS.
It also makes the HTTP calls to https://api.stripe/confirm when you add card and pay with Stripe Elements from client, but from a http local server from your pc, that it's not a HTTPS server and then it triggers the webhooks that subscription has been created and everything is handled on the backend side.

**Is this a security flaw?** Is the data sent encrypted/safe? Can it have some compliance issues?
If yes, what can I do about it? I don't really wanna add stripe subscriptions on website and not on Electron app.

Comment: I assume that if Stripe had any *real* problems with this, payments would not be processed. On the other hand, while it's not a real security flaw as long as you don't send any sensitive information to your Express server via HTTP, it could cause some concern among the more technical of your users. Bottom line is that you'll have to make sure that payment details are only ever transmitted in an encrypted fashion, AFAIK, but I'm no expert here.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Thank you for your response! I agree, I'm more concerned about what data I'm sending to https://api.stripe or my API which both have HTTPS enabled.

But if I send the data to a HTTPS server even if it's from a HTTP local server, it's still encrypted right? The response back from the HTTPS server to local server it should be encrypted as well I suppose, if it's coming from an HTTPS server.